# How to use Bart with PretrainedTransformerEmbedder?

Tags: allennlp

if i use `encoder = PretrainedTransformerEmbedder(model_name, sub_module="encoder")` as the encoder to pass to Bart(encoder=encoder), it reports error because it doesn't implement `get_input_dim()`, if i pass `encoder = PretrainedTransformerEmbedder(model_name, sub_module="encoder"), encoder = encoder.encoder` as the input encoder like metioned [here](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/4604), it reports error because the `PretrainedTransformerEmbedder(model_name, sub_module="encoder")` doesn't has an attribute `encoder`.
So how can i use the full bart model(including token_embed, position_embed) for seq2seq task in allennlp?

Comment: A whole snippet of a reproducible code would demonstrate the problem better

Answer (score 0):

If you just pass `encoder=None` (which is the default), the `Bart` model will use the native BART encoder. It sounds like that's what you want?